# POSTGRESQL - How to sum (date row 0 - date row 1) + (date row 2 - date row 3)

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know how I could make a sum of (date row 0 - date row 1) + (date row 2 - date row 3) and so on... group by userId.

Please refer to the screenshot below, I want to sum the time between every APP_OPENED and APP_QUIT event for **EACH** different idUser that logs into the app.

[image]

Result must be something like :

**idUser - diffTime**

2cf3...  - 25 seconds

504...  - 50 secondes

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: which events must be considered? is there only one OPENED and QUIT event by user?

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE* this doesn't work, you can try some of the code and make it work, but as it is now it is just substracting one row time from the previous row time even if previous was a QUIT event, use above instead.
This works but is extremely slow , so there must be a better way, maybe you can figure out from here:

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (event varchar(20), content varchar(85), mydate timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
;

INSERT INTO Mytable
    (event, content, mydate)
VALUES
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678",}','2017-04-26 12:00:58.176'),
    ('APP_QUIT', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:08.151'),
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:11.595'),
    ('APP_QUIT', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:28.144'),
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:34.51'),
    ('APP_QUIT', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:40.974'),
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2cf312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:14:30.689'),
    ('APP_USER_LOGGING_IN', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"504312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:16:41.905'),
    ('APP_QUIT', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"504312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:16:49.287'),
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"504312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:16:51.115'),
    ('APP_OPENED', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"504312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:17:26.866'),
    ('APP_QUIT', '{"connected":true,"idUser":"504312345678"}','2017-04-26 12:01:40.974');
```

=================================

```
select idUser, sum(difftime) from
(
SELECT split_part(content, '"', 6) IdUser,

(
        (
            DATE_PART('day', mydate::TIMESTAMP - lag(mydate) OVER (
                    ORDER BY mydate
                        ,split_part(content, '"', 6)
                    )::TIMESTAMP) * 24 + DATE_PART('hour', mydate::TIMESTAMP - lag(mydate) OVER (
                    ORDER BY mydate
                        ,split_part(content, '"', 6)
                    )::TIMESTAMP)
            ) * 60 + DATE_PART('minute', mydate::TIMESTAMP - lag(mydate) OVER (
                ORDER BY mydate
                    ,split_part(content, '"', 6)
                )::TIMESTAMP)
        ) * 60 + DATE_PART('second', mydate::TIMESTAMP - lag(mydate) OVER (
            ORDER BY mydate
                ,split_part(content, '"', 6)
            )::TIMESTAMP)  diffTime
FROM mytable
WHERE event IN (
        'APP_OPENED'
        ,'APP_QUIT'
        )

ORDER BY split_part(content, '"', 6)

) results
group by idUser
```

tested in sqlfiddle with postgreSQL 9.3 engine

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table events (event varchar(30), content json, event_date timestamp);
> insert into events values
> ('APP_OPENED',          '{"connected":true,"idUser":"1"}', '2017-04-26 12:00:58.176'),
> ('APP_QUIT',            '{"connected":true,"idUser":"1"}', '2017-04-26 12:01:08.151'),
> ('APP_OPENED',          '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2"}', '2017-04-26 12:01:11.595'),
> ('APP_QUIT',            '{"connected":true,"idUser":"2"}', '2017-04-26 12:01:28.144'),
> ('APP_OPENED',          '{"connected":true,"idUser":"3"}', '2017-04-26 12:01:34.51'),
> ('APP_QUIT',            '{"connected":true,"idUser":"3"}', '2017-04-26 12:01:40.974'),
> ('APP_OPENED',          '{"connected":true,"idUser":"4"}', '2017-04-26 12:14:30.689'),
> ('APP_USER_LOGGING_IN', '{"userId":"5"}',                  '2017-04-26 12:16:41.905'),
> ('APP_QUIT',            '{"connected":true,"idUser":"5"}', '2017-04-26 12:16:49.287'),
> ('APP_OPENED',          '{"connected":true,"idUser":"6"}', '2017-04-26 12:16:51.115'),
> ('APP_QUIT',            '{"connected":true,"idUser":"6"}', '2017-04-26 12:17:26.866');
> ```

According to you question I've considered that each action if formed by two events:

```
(APP_OPENED & APP_QUIT) or (APP_USER_LOGGING_IN & APP_QUIT)
```

The first step is to flag one reset point for every `APP_OPENED` or `APP_USER_LOGGING_IN`, that is the event that starts one event, and then assign a different group to every couple of events.

> ```
> --= Set reset points
> with setReset as 
> (
>     select   event, 
>              case when content->>'idUser' is null then content->>'userId' else content->>'idUser' end userId,
>              event_date,
>              case when event <> 'APP_QUIT' then 1 end reset_point
>     from     events
>     order by event_date
> )
>     --= Generates groups
>     , setGrp as
>     (
>         select   event, userId, event_date, 
>                  count(reset_point) over (order by event_date) grp
>         from     setReset
>         order by event_date
>     )
>     select * from setGrp;
> ```
>
> ```
> event               | userid | event_date              | grp
> :------------------ | :----- | :---------------------- | --:
> APP_OPENED          | 1      | 2017-04-26 12:00:58.176 |   1
> APP_QUIT            | 1      | 2017-04-26 12:01:08.151 |   1
> APP_OPENED          | 2      | 2017-04-26 12:01:11.595 |   2
> APP_QUIT            | 2      | 2017-04-26 12:01:28.144 |   2
> APP_OPENED          | 3      | 2017-04-26 12:01:34.51  |   3
> APP_QUIT            | 3      | 2017-04-26 12:01:40.974 |   3
> APP_OPENED          | 4      | 2017-04-26 12:14:30.689 |   4
> APP_USER_LOGGING_IN | 5      | 2017-04-26 12:16:41.905 |   5
> APP_QUIT            | 5      | 2017-04-26 12:16:49.287 |   5
> APP_OPENED          | 6      | 2017-04-26 12:16:51.115 |   6
> APP_QUIT            | 6      | 2017-04-26 12:17:26.866 |   6
> ```

Finally you can get time difference of each group:

> ```
> --= Set reset points
> with setReset as 
> (
>     select   event, 
>              case when content->>'idUser' is null then content->>'userId' else content->>'idUser' end userId,
>              event_date,
>              case when event <> 'APP_QUIT' then 1 end reset_point
>     from     events
>     order by event_date
> )
>     --= Generates groups
>     , setGrp as
>     (
>         select   event, userId, event_date, 
>                  count(reset_point) over (order by event_date) grp
>         from     setReset
>         order by event_date
>     )
>     ---= Calculate datediff of each group
>     select userid, extract(epoch from(max(event_date) - min(event_date))) 
>     from   setGrp
>     group by grp, userId
>     having   count(grp) > 1
>     order by grp;
> ```
>
> ```
> userid | date_part
> :----- | :--------
> 1      | 9.975    
> 2      | 16.549   
> 3      | 6.464    
> 5      | 7.382    
> 6      | 35.751
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80ac8443b9dfb22fa5d642e210452bb9)*